# how to make an object of array from a list of arrays. (Using angularjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have a list of arrays with me. Here it is

```
array1= [ab,bc];
array2= [12,23];
array3= [vw,wx];
```

Now i need to make an object of array like the one mentioned below from the above list

```
[ab,12, vw] as 1st array
[bc,23,wx] as 2nd array
```

And these two arrays should now be in a single object. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Could be elaborate little more on "And these two arrays should now be in a single object" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. This is more dynamic implementation with no hard-coding of assumptions.

```
function prepareObjectOfArrays(myArrays){
    var myObj = [];
    var maxArrLength = calculateMaxLength(myArrays);
    for(var i=0; i<maxArrLength; i++){
        var tempArr = [];
        for(var j=0; j<myArrays.length; j++){
            tempArr.push(myArrays[j][i]);
        }
        myObj.push(tempArr);
    }
    console.log(myObj);
}

function calculateMaxLength(myArrays){
    var maxLength = 0;
    for(var j=0; j<myArrays.length; j++){
        var tempLength = myArrays[j].length;
        if(maxLength < tempLength){
            maxLength = tempLength;
        }
    }
    return maxLength;
}
```

Now invoke as below:

```
var array1= ['ab','bc'];
var array2= [12,23];
var array3= ['vw','wx'];
prepareObjectOfArrays([array1, array2, array3]);
```

As I said, this is more dynamic implementation with no hard-coding of assumptions, and will even work with more type of inputs. There could be more corner cases but this is almost fully dynamic. Check with below inputs:

```
var array1= ['ab','bc','de', 'er'];
var array2= [12,23,34];
var array3= ['vw','wx','yz'];

var array1= ['ab','bc','de', 'er'];
var array2= [12,23,34,45,56,78];
var array3= ['vw','wx','yz'];
```

Comment: this wld be more dyanmic. as i have equal number of length in each array, i dont have to work on the extra logic. thanks hagarwal.

Comment: No problems, Ayesha. If your lengths are different in each array then just loop all array, store the length and update if current length is greater than previous length .. Make a function for this and call it from the place where I have added the comment so that maximum length goes in `var maxArrLength`, rest everything implementation in the answer will take care.

Comment: Check my latest edit. I implemented that, you should be mostly good in all scenarios.

Comment: @Ayesha Why would you prefer some code which has been coded from scratch rather than using some library which is well tested. This code might have some edge cases which might not be evident now but could be encountered later ?

Comment: @hagrawal How is your code different from zip function of lodash ?

Comment: @KunalKapadia Buddy, there are hell lot of reasons but I would tell only one which is more sufficient (*atleast if you are also talking about a production level Enterprise application*) to not to prefer zip function - if you will keep on adding these kind of third party libraries for requirements like this then your application will eventually explode and become tightly dependent on 3rd party libraries. That's it. Now, if you understand the curse of such a dependency then you understand my point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) function from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs) library.

```
_.zip([ab, bc], [12, 23], [vw, wx]);
// -> [[ab, 12, vw], [bc, 23, wx]]
```

Comment: If the OP is looking for an object, they would want to use _.zipObject right?  https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject

Comment: @molson504x It is not exactly clear by "And these two arrays should now be in a single object" ?

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
array1= ['ab','bc',33];
array2= [12,23,35];
array3= ['vw','wx',34,'hh'];
array4= ['vw1','wx1',36];
//object
var mixarrays = {
  minmax:'min',//decide col max or min
  decide_size:function(arrs){
    var size = this.minmax=='max'? 0 :999999;
    for(i in arrs){
      if(arrs[i].length > size && this.minmax=='max'){
        size = arrs[i].length;
      }else if(arrs[i].length < size && this.minmax=='min'){
        size = arrs[i].length;
      }
    }
    return size;
  },
  init:function(arrs){
    cols = this.decide_size(arrs);
    var mixedarray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<cols;i++){
      mixedarray[i] = [];
      for(j in arrs){
        mixedarray[i].push(arrs[j][i]);
      }
    }
    return mixedarray;
  }
};

//[array1,array2,array3,array4];//array of arrays
console.log(mixarrays.init([array1,array2,array3,array4]));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/n2nyz3mc/)